# Is it possible to run a Java program with JVM only?

Tags: jvm

Is it possible to run a Java program with JVM only? (without JRE)

I don't ask if we can run all the programs, also those that needs access to libraries, I'm asking for the most basic program, after the program was compiled
(Is there a program that can run with only JVM)

Comment: Can you imagine how a Java program could work with a JVM, without even the class definition of `java.lang.Object` or `java.lang.String`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You would need a wrapper to make the file executable. target environment would not require java runtime installation in this case. to be clear you are embedding the JRE inside. have look at [Excelsior JET](https://www.excelsiorjet.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run the program without JRE. But you can run the program without JDK, if the program is already compiled.

**Java Runtime Environment (JRE) is a software package that contains what is required to run a Java program** - Wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the picture below you will better understand how java works:[CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTTOC.jpg)

Java Runtime Environment contains JVM, class libraries, and other supporting files. It does not contain any development tools such as compiler, debugger, etc. **Actually JVM runs the program, and it uses the class libraries, and other supporting files provided in JRE. If you want to run any java program, you need to have JRE installed in the system.**